# Access crontab process in a terminal using ssh

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, terminal, cron

I have already a two python script running on a rpi on startup with crontab, syntax is something like this:

```
@reboot python /home/scripts/my_script_a.py > /home/log/a.log 2>&1 &
@reboot python /home/scripts/my_script_b.py > /home/log/b.log 2>&1 &
```

The scripts can take several hours to complete, so by now I'm logging the info, and accesing via sftp to see the output, but I would like to open the process output in a ssh terminal, send commands to the scripts, and see the output in real time, is this possible?

I'm logging in via ssh with the same user as the scripts are running.
Thanks for your time.

Comment: To get their output in realtime, you can very simply do: `ssh myRpi tail -f /home/log/a.log`

Answer (score 0):

You may find the `tailf` of `tail -f` command useful.

For example:

```
tailf /home/log/a.log
```

Will print the output in real time.

Comment: Thank you very much!, i prefer the other solution, but this command will be usefull for me in the future, cheers

Answer (score 0):

you can use the screen command to do that.

Check this:

https://serverfault.com/questions/233084/how-do-i-use-crontab-to-start-a-screen-session

Comment: **Thank you very much for your help**, i will learn about this screen command, looks very usefull!.